# VB6 connecting to MySQL5.7.16 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: mysql, vb6, window, odbc

I compiled my `VB.exe` program on a PC and run it on a `Window Server 2012R2` server as I can't install VB6 at the server.

I can't establish the following connection.

```
sDatabase = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};"
sDatabase = sDatabase & "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3307;UID=root;Password=Pass;Database=Database;OPTION=3;"

Set gConn = New ADODB.Connection
gConn.Open sDatabase
```

I got the following error

[image: error]

I am sure that all the parameters are correct because I have another ASP Classic webpage that connects to MySQL successfully.

I don't know where to start debugging. Is it got to do with the following?

[image: DNS]

Comment: If the machine you are running this on is a 64 bit machine try changing your connection string to add Provider=MSDASQL; `Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in your last screenshot, look at the title of the ODBC dialog.  It states `(64-bit)`.  Use this one to access the 32-Bit version of ODBC:

c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe.

And look here for details:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2008/10/17/why-my-32-bit-applications-cannot-see-the-odbc-dsns-that-i-created-on-my-64-bit-machine/

Comment: Thanks @tcarvin I just installed the following files mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.10-win32 and everything is working.